# What's the meaning of a pressure coefficient in fluid mechanics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

I have a jet of air leaving a contraction from a pressurized tank at a velocity of 28.8 m/s and it's being directed towards a small object equipped with static pressure holes on its surface that give a reading of -310 Pa.

I then had to calculate the maximum velocity on the body. I found it to be 36.5 m/s but I'm not really sure what the physical interpretation of this maximum velocity. I know the air must be traveling around the object and the stagnation point is at the center of the object where the air velocity if 0. Does this maximum velocity occur on the outside of the object as the air is curving around it?

Also, what is the term "pressure coefficient"? I have to find the pressure coefficient at the stagnation point but I'm not really sure what that term is...

Comment: ""leaving a contraction to a pressurized tank"" could You explain how that works?

Comment: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_coefficient) explains pressure coefficient.

Comment: Meant to say leaving a contraction from a pressurized tank. My teacher calls it a contraction when the tube/pipe to the outlet is smaller than the tank

Comment: Ah, just the irrelevant difference between "to" and "from".